# animating view change with uitabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uitabbarcontroller

I am wanting to animate my view change, however I am not sure where to put my animation since I have a UITabBarController controlling which view I am on and what I can switch too.. This is being declared in my appdelegate.m file as per the xcode template.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Or their is the area in each viewcontroller where everything gets loaded... Im thinking it might be better to initialize the animation in here.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Super", @"Super");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SuperIcon"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

As I have not done alot of animation with views before I am woundering where I could declare this peice of code that will hopefully animate my view change when a UITabBarButton is touched....

```
[UIView transitionWithView:containerView
           duration:0.2
           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
           animations:^{ [fromView removeFromSuperview]; [containerView addSubview:toView]; 
           completion:NULL];
```

or have I missed the boat completely and is their somewhere else I should be doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code in the viewWillAppear method

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                       forView:self.view cache:YES];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This worked for me for a tabBar controller based app.

Answer (score 1):

Try that animation in code in viewWillAppear method

Comment: Try adding in each of the viewcontrollers (which you initiate with tabbarcontroller)viewWillAppear method the above code replacing the containerView with self.view and i guess [super viewWillAppear:animated] is not necessary.

Comment: I tried this and I was giving me errors.. about the containnerView.. Will need to do some more research into this.

Comment: Since you want the animation to happen when the view is changed , try in viewWillDisappear method.

Comment: I think the trouble is coming in the way I am declaring some of the attributed to the **transitionWithView** function.. I need to so more research to see if this is even possible with a tabbarcontroller.

Comment: this is what I have so far.. but I still need to figure out what goes in the animations field.


    [super transitionFromViewController:FirstViewController toViewController:SecondViewController duration:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:<#^(void)animations#> completion:NULL];

Comment: Try the 2nd answer I have posted.